# Ηow to append an variable with many words at the beginning of a file

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following variable

```
lanint="β— lan.1021 (inactive -> active - 1 Change)"
```

and I want to append it to the begin of a file
I use the following code, but it shows me an error because I use spaces and special characters.

```
awk -i inplace 'BEGINFILE{print strftime("%d/%m/%Y - %T") " My info : '$lanint'"}{print}' log.txt
```

Can you help me how to do it ?

Comment: If it isn't a multiline string then you can pass it as argument to awk `awk -v lanint="$lanint" ...`

Comment: Even if it is a multiline string, you can do that.

Comment: The simple and obvious fix is to use double quotes around the string, though this could introduce Awk syntax errors; in that sense, @Fravadona's solution is more robust.

Comment: @tripleee This look like a bug produced by parenhesis is *`regex`*!

Comment: Thank you @Fravadona to pass it as an argument work just fine.

Comment: @tripleee you are right for the multiline string.